# Run shell script in parallel with more jobs than CPUs, and after a job is finished, instantly take the available spot

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I'm running a shell script `script.sh` in parallel which in each of its lines goes to a folder and run a Fortran code:

```
cd folder1 && ./code & 
cd folder2 && ./code &
cd folder3 && ./code &
cd folder4 && ./code &
..
cd folder 96 && ./code
wait 
cd folder 97 && ./code
..
..
..
cd folder2500 && ./code.sh
```

There are around 2500 Folders and code outputs are independent from each other. I have access to 96 CPUs and each job uses around 1% of CPU, so I run 96 jobs in parallel using the `&` key and `wait` command. Due to different reasons, not all 96 jobs finish at the same time. Some of them take 40 minutes, some of them 90 minutes, an important difference. So I was wondering if it is possible that the jobs that finish earlier  use the available CPUs in order to optimize the execution time.

I tried also with GNU Parallel:

`parallel -a script.sh` but it had the same issue, and I could not find in internet somebody with a similar problem.

Comment: You have not explained what "the issue" is.  Why can't you start all of the jobs and let the OS do its job of scheduling them?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel 'cd {} && ./code' ::: folder*
```

That will keep all your cores busy, starting a new job immediately as each job finishes.

---

If you only want to run 48 jobs in parallel, use:

```
parallel -j 48 ...
```

If you want to do a dry run and see what would run but without actually running anything, use:

```
parallel --dry-run ...
```

If you want to see a progress report, use:

```
parallel --progress ...
```

Answer (score 2):

One `bash/wait -n` approach:

```
jobmax=96
jobcnt=0

for ((i=1;i<=2500;i++))
do
    ((++jobcnt))
    [[ "${jobcnt}" -gt "${jobmax}" ]] && wait -n && ((--jobcnt))   # if jobcnt > 96 => wait for a job to finish, decrement jobcnt, then continue with next line ...
    ( cd "folder$i" && ./code ) &                                  # kick off new job
done

wait                                                               # wait for rest of jobs to complete
```

**NOTES:**

- when the jobs complete quickly (eg, < 1 sec) it's possible that more than one job could complete during the `wait -n; start new job; wait -n` cycle, in which case you could end up with less than `jobmax` jobs running at a time (ie, `jobcnt` is higher than the actual number of running jobs)
- however, in this scenario where each job is expected to take XX minutes to complete the likelihood of multiple jobs completing during the `wait -n; start new job; wait -n` cycle should be greatly diminished (if not eliminated)

Comment: This worked wonderfully :). Thank you thank you. I will monitor that no issues happen in the `wait -n`  cycle